# Cron Run resulted in Fatal Error Message

Tags: cron

Using Drupal 6.22 
PHP 5.2.17
PHP memory limit - 150M

Last time I ran Cron was 2 weeks 19 hours ago

I am experiencing no errors with the site but opted to run Cron manually and received the following error message

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 157286400 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7680 bytes) in /home4/xxx/public_html/xxx/includes/theme.inc on line 1078

Is this an error message I need to be concerned about?
If yes, How do I fix it?
And...Is running Cron a necessity, if the site is functioning fine everywhere else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Allowed memory size" errors on common tasks](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13797/allowed-memory-size-errors-on-common-tasks)

Comment: I closed the question for the given reason because the OP commented with [_It's odd, but it is working now_](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/cron-run-resulted-in-fatal-error-message?noredirect=1#comment8881_8692).

Answer (score 1):

Whatever cron is doing, you'll need to allow it more memory for it to succeed. You can find out about increasing PHP's `memory_limit` at http://drupal.org/node/207036

However, it looks like you already have `memory_limit` set to a high value for a small site.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I just tried to rerun Cron and it ran successfully.  It's odd, but it is working now so I think that I might be good.  Thank you.