# "Allowed memory size" errors on common tasks

Tags: 7

I get this error all the time when I'm doing common admin tasks, such as enabling modules.

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit your `sites/default/settings.php` file, and change the line to set the memory limit:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '100M');
```

or increase `memory_limit` in your `php.ini` file.