# drush pm-update of 6.27 to 6.28 yields this error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes

Tags: updating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Allowed memory size” errors on common tasks](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13797/allowed-memory-size-errors-on-common-tasks)

we put our site into maintenance mode, 
temporariliy removed some symbolic links that have confused drush in the past,
and tried to do this:
[~/drupal-6.25]# drush pm-update

where we got this error:

Refreshing update status information ...

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 199690 bytes) in /home/kettles/drupal-6.25/modules/update/update.module on line 549
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]
Error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to
allocate 199690 bytes) in
/home/kettles/drupal-6.25/modules/update/update.module, line 549
[~/drupal-6.25]#

The directory is called drupal-6.25 but really holds a 6.27 install.

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried to increase the memory limit in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://drupal.org/node/76156) thread.

What you need to do basically is to increase the memory in your `php.ini` file. Start with `128M` and if you are still getting that error, try with more.

Comment: We searched online for this error and had already set it to 128M; How much larger should we go ?

Comment: @newadmin It's difficult to answer that; try increasing it gradually until you see the errors disappear